# Filtering json blocks based on specfic string/value pair using python

Tags: python, json, filter

a beginner here. Can you please provide me with a python code to understand how to select specific value/key from a jason block such as below.

```
"listeners": [
        {
            "ip_address": "::",
            "node": "rabbit@bx1",
            "port": 5672,
            "protocol": "amqp",
            "socket_opts": {
                "backlog": 128,
                "exit_on_close": false,
                "linger": [
                    true,
                    0
                ],
                "nodelay": true
            }
        },
        {
            "ip_address": "::",
            "node": "rabbit@bx1",
            "port": 25672,
            "protocol": "clustering",
            "socket_opts": []
        },
        {
            "ip_address": "::",
            "node": "rabbit@bx1",
            "port": 15672,
            "protocol": "http",
            "socket_opts": {
                "port": 15672
            }
        }
    ],
```

For an instance what would it take for me filter only "ip address" and its corresponding value using python's jason module? To get something like below.

```
"listeners": [
        {
            "ip_address": "::",
                        }
        },
        {
            "ip_address": "::",
        },
                  }
        }
    ],
```

Please advice guys. Thank you in advance.

Comment: something "like below" is not possible as there is twice the same key `"id"`...

Comment: @n00dl3 thank you. As i said first time im working with json. I changed the jason block and  can you take a look now. Please if the jason block formatting is wrong correct it. I just need to understand how I write a python code for my purpose is all.

Comment: Read about [Python Dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have a list of dicts:

```
>>> listeners = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 1}]
```

This means you can use the map function on the list to filter the dicts:

```
>>> map(lambda d: d["a"], listeners) 
[1, 3]
```

This is now a plain list. You can also (re-)create a dict within the lambda function:

```
>>> map(lambda d: {"a": d["a"]}, listeners) 
[{'a': 1}, {'a': 3}]
```

Is this what you needed?